# record a short screencast in solus

Tags: video, screencasting, solus

[image]

I had tried to start screencast by the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. Although it didn't start. Why this is happening? It was working fine when I was using Mint, Ubuntu, Fedora.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if recording a screencast and screen recording is the same thing, but if it is, I recommend installing simplescreenrecorder, and just using that, you can even give it your own custom keybindings to make it start up whenever you need to record something. You could possible just leave it running in the background and just apply your keybinding to let it start/stop recording whenever you press it.

You can install it via `sudo eopkg install simplescreenrecorder`